# Inconsistent and erratic mouse wheel in Linux while moving the mouse pointer

Tags: linux, mouse, scroll-wheel

I have Manjaro Linux in VirtualBox, and in some applications such as the terminal the mouse wheel seems not to register many of the scroll ticks. Sometimes it scrolls fine, then suddenly it scrolls only half as much or stops scrolling at all. In other applications such as Firefox, the scroll wheel always works.

After some experimentation I found that **I can't scroll at all while I'm moving the mouse pointer**. Yet, when I hold the pointer perfectly still, scrolling works as expected.

There are some related questions on this site, but none have this specific issue caused by moving the mouse pointer while scrolling in Linux.

Comment: I think this is caused by https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/679

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found [this post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=401248#p401248) on the VirtualBox forums in a thread that exactly describes my problem. It seems to be unrelated to VirtualBox, as VMWare shows the same behavior.

The solution that worked for me:

1. Check that you're currently using `libinput`.

   ```
   $ grep "Using input" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
   [     0.000] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
   [     0.001] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
   [     0.002] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
   [     0.003] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'VirtualBox mouse integration'
   [     0.004] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'VirtualBox USB Tablet'
   [     0.005] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
   [     0.006] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse'
   [     0.007] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'VirtualBox USB Tablet'
   ```
2. Install the `evdev` input drivers.
   On Manjaro this is found in the `xf86-input-evdev` package, which was already installed.
3. Enable the `evdev` drivers by modifying the X11 configuration.
   In the directory `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` I already had a file `10-evdev.conf` with the `evdev` configuration. It was just overridden by the higher-priority `40-libinput.conf` configuration. So all I had to do was:

   ```
   cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
   sudo mv 10-evdev.conf 80-evdev.conf
   ```
4. Restart.
5. Verify that the `evdev` drivers are now used instead:

   ```
   $ grep "Using input" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
   [     0.000] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
   [     0.001] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Sleep Button'
   [     0.002] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
   [     0.003] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'VirtualBox mouse integration'
   [     0.004] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'VirtualBox USB Tablet'
   [     0.005] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
   [     0.006] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse'
   [     0.007] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'VirtualBox USB Tablet'
   ```

   This however didn't yet fix my problem. Apparently I needed `imwheel` too.
6. Install `imwheel`.
   On Arch, I had to install the [imwheel](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/imwheel/) AUR package.
7. Run `imwheel` to verify that this fixes the issue.

   ```
   $ imwheel
   ```
8. All that remained was to make `imwheel` run at startup. I run this command, as it only intercepts the scroll wheel:

   ```
   imwheel -b 45
   ```

This fixed the issues! Scrolling is now working correctly in all applications.

Comment: You are a hero. I struggled with this for months. Thanks a lot! Can confirm this is working on my XFCE Manjaro as well. That being said, Emacs now doesn't want to scroll: `C-M-(` and `C-M-)` is undefined, it says.

Comment: Fixes my problem on KDE neon 5.14 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). See https://askubuntu.com/a/304653/112818 for more details on how to config `imwheel`

Comment: I can fix the scrollwheel too by switching to evdev, but not in Qt apps. There it still doesn't work, while moving the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue running "Mint 19.3 XFCE" on "VBox 6.0.18" (Host: Windows 10 Professional).

All I did to fix it was go to Settings / "Mouse and Touchpad" and in Devices turn off "VirtualBox mouse integration".

I have not yet noticed any side effects of my now less integrated mouse, except that it scrolls perfectly.

Comment: Seems perfect for Xubuntu 20.04.2 LTS as well! (Host: Win 10 Home)

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Pelsmaeker's answer was exactly what I needed! I'm running Ubuntu Budgie 19.10 on VirtualBox 6.15 on a Windows 10 host.

For users using Ubuntu instead of Manjaro, `xserver-xorg-input-evdev` is the package you'll want. To install it, run the following command:

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev`

Answer (score 1):

After banging my head against a wall for months with this I finally used imwheel.  I have tried all the above to include uninstalling/reinstalling guest additions and changes to Virtualbox mouse settings, etc.

```
sudo apt install imwheel
```

fixed.

Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on Debian 11 (bullseye) with Xfce 4.16 and VirtualBox 6.1.40.

1. I have installed the evdev drivers.

```
apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

2. I moved the 40-evdev.conf file.

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
mv 40-evdev.conf 80-evdev.conf
```

3. In "Settings" -> "Mouse and Touchpad" -> "Devices" turn off "VirtualBox mouse integration".

[Show this image to turn off virtualbox mouse integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW1w8.png)