# Linux Touchpad: Slowly scrolling down "chunky" in (Java?) apps that don't scroll continuously

Tags: linux, java, mouse, touchpad, scrolling

I noticed this on my Xubuntu 18.04 Laptop, using the touchpad and the Synaptics driver:

When I scroll down slowly (using the two finger scroll gesture) in, say, LibreOffice Calc (which has rows of cells [Edit: same with scrolling horizontally]) and the commit history in SmartGit (which has rows of commits), the gesture doesn't scroll the view consistently, often not at all. Conversely, the history in Firefox (`Ctrl+Shift+H`) does not show this behavior, so maybe it's got something to do with Java?

The behavior seems like a calculation of the form `yPos = (int) (yPos + increment)` is taking place: an increment of `+0.1` won't work, but an increment of `-0.1` or `+1.0` will. When the scroll speed is around `+1.0`, small changes will push it to round up or down, causing erratic scrolling behavior.

The behavior depends on scroll amounts (slow scrolling shows this more pronouncedly), direction (scrolling up and down are affected differently), the fact that I'm using the touchpad or Synaptics (mouse is not affected by this) and apparently some property of the application (Firefox is not affected).

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1270811/inconsistent-and-erratic-mouse-wheel-in-linux-while-moving-the-mouse-pointer) seemed related but I'm not using `libinput` and my symptoms are different, so I didn't want to try switching to `evdev` just yet (I'm glad I got the three finger tap to work with synaptics).

Any ideas how this could be worked around? "evdev is definitely the way to go" is also a welcome response, if you have reasons or experience for saying so.

Comment: By 'doesn't scroll consistently' do you mean that it jumps whole rows at a time instead of being smooth, or do you mean that it jumps varying distances for the same gesture?

Comment: I hoped to get it across with what I said about rounding, I'll try again: basically, scrolling (down) slowly doesn't scroll at all. In a typical gesture where I accelerate and decelerate, it will scroll a few rows in the middle but start late and stop early. Imagine `yPos = (int) (yPos + increment)`. an increment of `+0.1` won't work, but an increment of `-0.1` or `+1.0` will.

Comment: Does anything change if you switch to xorg-input-libinput?